# Allocate Json Array into NSArray (JSONKit)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How can allocate that jSon response into a `NSArray`?

jSON:

```
[{"city":"Entry 1"},{"city":"Entry 2"},{"city":"Entry 3"}]
```

Code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonData) {
        cellsCity = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[dict objectForKey:@"city"], nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: the line NSArray *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData]; already gets you your JSON into an array. What did you mean by using the verb "allocate" ?

Comment: @IcanZilb This way it will pick up all `city` entries or just the first one?

Comment: Just add "NSLog(@"obj:%@", jsonData)" after that line and you will see.

Comment: @IcanZilb Its not working, get error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get JSON into Objects via Apples built in serializer:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:aData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if(error){
    NSLog(@"Error parsing json");
    return;
} else {...}
```

So there is no need to use external frameworks IMHO (unlees you need performance and JSONKit is, like they say, really 25-40% faster than NSJSONSerialization.

**EDIT**

Through your comments I guess this is what you want

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //First get the array of dictionaries
    NSArray *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData];
    NSMutableArray *cellsCity = [NSMutableArray array];
    //then iterate through each dictionary to extract key-value pairs 
    for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonData) {
        [cellsCity addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"city"]];
    }
```

}

Comment: Using `JSONKit` how I can do that?

Comment: You are sending a json object in an array, so your line NSArray *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData]; is just fine. That's all you need.

Comment: With my code the cellsCity return only `Entry 3`, and using `NSArray *jsonData = [responseData objectFromJSONData];` I get error.

Comment: I would like `cellsCity` return an array with `Entry 1`, `Entry 2`, `Entry 3`.

Comment: Sure you are getting just entry 3. You are overwriting cellsCity in the loop so that only the last entry (3) will "survive"!!! See my edits